# Spacy, using nlp.pipe on large dataset in python, multiprocessing leads to processes going in sleep state. How to proper use all CPU cores?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, sleep, spacy

I'm working on a NLP classification problem over a large database of emails (~1 million). I need to use spacy to parse texts and I'm using the nlp.pipe() method as `nlp.pipe(emails,n_process=CPU_CORES, batch_size=20)` to loop over the dataset.
The code works but I'm facing a (maybe not so)weird behavior:
the processes are being created but they are all in SLEEP state but one, casually some of them go in RUN state for a few seconds and then back to sleep. So I find myself with one single process using one core at 100% but of course the script not using all the CPU cores.
It's like the processes don't get "fed" input data from pipe.

*Does anybody know how to properly use spacy nlp pipe or anyway how to avoid this situation*? no way to use nlp.pipe with the GPU?

Thank you very much!
Sandro

EDIT: *I still have no solution but i've noticed that if I set the `batch_size=divmod(len(emails),CPU_CORES)`, the processes all starts running at 100% CPU and after a few seconds they all switch to sleeping state but one. It really looks like some element in spacy pipe gets locked while waiting for something to end.... any idea??*

EDIT2: *Setting `batch_size=divmod(len(emails),CPU_CORES)` while processing a large dataset leads inevitably to a spacy memory error:*

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (1232821, 288) and data type float32

*thing that is maybe not so weird as my machine has 10GB of RAM and (1232821×288×32)bits / 8 = 1.4GB multiplied by 6 (CPU_CORES) leads to a 8.5GB of RAM needed. Therefore I guess that, having other stuff in memory already, it turns out to be plausible. *

Comment: Not an expert in multiprocessing but have you tried increasing the batch_size to like 500 or 1000 (maybe more regarding your high number of samples) ? 20 seem rather small, it means every 20 samples the processes need rescheduling. Alternatively, you can [disable](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#disabling) some pipes in your spacy model (I generally am using only the POStag)

Comment: Hi @ygorg, yes I tried to set the batch size to many different values (<= 10.000) but nothing changed, all processes in sleep state but one. Disabling some pipeline component is unfortunately not an option as I need all of them. Let see if anybody else have any suggestion. Thank you for your reply! :)

Comment: On GPU it's probably easier to optimize `batch_size` for your text lengths + GPU memory and use one process. Depending on the number of processes / RAM, CPU batch size can be 1000+, GPU batch size may need to be a lot smaller. Additionally if you're using a transformer model you may be running into issues related to torch and OpenMP (on CPU or GPU): https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17199

Comment: @aab thanks for your reply, I'm not sure how to "force" spacy nlp.pipe() to use the GPU?

Comment: Could the cause be that what I do inside the `for doc in nlp.pipe(...):` loop is too slow in term od execution time and therefore spacy pipe somehow has to wait for all the batches to be processed? it's just a guess as I'm not a spacy or multiprocessing expert....

Comment: If you want to use the GPU, call `spacy.require_gpu()` before calling `nlp.pipe`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using n_process=n works well for some models, like en_core_web_lg, but fails with others, such as en_core_web_trf.

For whatever reason, en_core_web_trf seems to use all cores with just a batch_size specified, whereas en_core_web_lg uses just one unless n_process=n is given. Likewise, en_core_web_trf fails with a closure error if n_process=n is specified.

Comment: I'm using en_core_web_lg but the main issue for me is the processes are going to sleep and (apparently) randomly being waken up instead of being running all together the whole time. Thanks for your contribution anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found an improvement but honestly the behavior it's not really clear to me. Now the sleeping processes are way less, with most of them stable running and a few sleeping or switching between the two states.
What I've done was to clean and speedup all the code inside the for loop and set the nlp.pipe args like this:

`for e in nlp.pipe(emails,n_process=CPU_CORES-1, batch_size=200):`

If anybody have any explanation about this or any suggestion on how to improve even more, it's of course more than welcome :)